# Interacción de base de datos MySQL con aplicación

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Supongamos que tengo mi programa hecho y configurada la BD para que interactúe con el programa perfectamente, entro en la aplicación, y hago nuevos registros, etc.

La pregunta es la siguiente:
¿Tengo que estar conectado a internet para que mysql registre los movimientos que haga, no?
¿Tengo que loguearme en mysql para poder funcionar con la aplicación o eso se puede configurar para que lo haga automáticamente?

Comment: Creo que mas alla de las respuestas que te den, deberias revisar conceptos de bases de datos y de programacion en general. Tu pregunta no es mala, pero demuestra que te faltan conceptos mas alla de las respuestas que te dieron.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te responderé a riesgo que me cierren la respuesta, antes que nada, antes incluso de la Base de Datos, debes comprender el paradigma Cliente Servidor, esto te servirá para comprender todas las aplicaciones:

Servidor: proveedor de algún recurso o servicio.

Cliente:  maquinas que usan algún servicio.

Así podrías encontrar por ejemplo cuando te conectas al banco, el servidor sería la página del banco y el cliente seria tu móvil o la PC personal a través de la cual te conectas. También puedes encontrar esta arquitectura a nivel local, dentro de tu red, cuando te conectas a tu Wifi o a tu red domestica, lo primero que hace el router es asignarte una IP mediante el servicio DHCP (servidor DHCP) al cual tu maquina (cliente) esta tratando de conectarse, entonces para el caso de una Base de datos este es un servidor de Base de datos (servidor) y por ende puede funcionar localmente dentro de tu red, como localhost (solo en tu pc) o en algún sitio de internet, pero eso ya esta en otra capa.

Comment: De diez! thnks!

Comment: Esto solo es funcional para cliente servidor, y no siempre es el estado real de una app (OP ni siquiera lo especifica)

Answer (score 4):

Primero necesita que la comunicación entre su aplicación y la base de datos funcione. Si están en la misma máquina, no importa la red o Internet, si están en diferentes máquinas en la misma red, solo necesita que esta red esté funcionando y que ambas máquinas puedan "verse" entre sí, si no lo están en la misma red, por ejemplo, la aplicación está en su máquina y está utilizando una base de datos online, entonces necesita Internet.

---

**Usted** no necesita iniciar ninguna sesión, **su aplicación debe hacerlo**. Tienes que codificar:

```
- Abre la conexión a la base de datos (usando dirección/IP, usuario, contraseña)
- Realizar la consulta
- Obtener los resultados
- Cerrar la conexión
```

El "inicio de sesión" se realiza mediante el código, cuando abre la conexión, no manualmente por usted.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada como te han comentado, me parece que por tus Preguntas no has realizado una investigacion previa o un estudio previo.

como punto de partida te recomendaria realizar una investigacion/estudio de proyecto a implementar, dependiendo de lo que estes haciendo puede que:

1. requieras o no internet para conecarte a la base de datos.
2. puede que normalmente la aplicacion y su configuracion incluyan ya la conectividad a la base de datos y no requiera que el usuario introdusca una segunda credencial en la aplicacion para obtener acceso a la base de datos.

Entonces conceptualmente tienes que entender que una base de datos es un recursos que necesita ser consumido mediante un protocolo y que normalmente para lograrlo tiene que pasar por una capa de seguridad y de acceso independientemente que sea local o en la red o por internet.

para que adquieras un conocimiento basico inicial te dejo este [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKOiEXlFNeM&list=PLQxX2eiEaqbwcW3dkmUqJq7B-SXHyCglf)

en la medida que continues estudiando y desarrollando proyecto entenderas de la multitud de formas en las que puedes trabajar con base de datos y podras observas que existe multiples respuestas a tus preguntas y que dependeran 100% de tu proyecto, requerimientos y escenarios.